# parsing AggregationOutput mongo java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregate that returns 3 results

```
{ "serverUsed" : "/127.0.0.1:27017" , "result" : [ { "_id" : "luke" , "times" : 56} , { "_id" : "albert" , "times" : 28} , { "_id" : "matt" , "times" : 28}] , "ok" : 1.0}
```

however when I try to iterate over the results, the code enter an endless loop (can't understand why!!)

```
AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate( match1, unwind, match2, group, sort, limit);

Iterable<DBObject> list= output.results();
        while(list.iterator().hasNext()){

            String id = (String) list.iterator().next().get("_id");
            int times = Integer.parseInt(list.iterator().next().get("times").toString());

            System.out.println("ID IS "+id+" time: "+times);
        }
```

Also the output repeats the first result:

```
ID IS luke time: 56
ID IS luke time: 56
ID IS luke time: 56
ID IS luke time: 56
ID IS luke time: 56
...
```

I really don;t understand why this iteration is not working. Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are using new iterator every time you access a field in `DBObject`, ie you're using `list.iterator()` several times within the loop. `list.iterator().next()` returns you the first element in the collection. So you end up accessing the first `DBObject`.

Try this:

```
Iterable<DBObject> list= output.results();
while(list.iterator().hasNext()){
    DBObject obj = list.iterator().next();
    String id = obj.get("_id");
    int times = Integer.parseInt(obj.get("times").toString());

    System.out.println("ID IS "+id+" time: "+times);
}
```

Or perhaps use a foreach loop:

```
for (DBObject obj : output.results()) {
    String id = obj.get("_id");
    int times = Integer.parseInt(obj.get("times").toString());
    System.out.println("ID IS "+id+" time: "+times);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know, this is an old thread, and it's already been answered, but the answers are optimizations.  The actual *reason* why you are getting the repeated answers is that each time you request .iterator(), it returns back an iterator object that starts from the top of the list.

So the while loop condition of:

```
list.iterator().hasNext()
```

will always return true.  Correspondingly, the subsequent

```
list.iterator().next()
```

will always return back the first element.

What should be done is this:

```
AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate( match1, unwind, match2, group, sort, limit);
Iterable<DBObject> list= output.results();
Iterator<DBObject> iterator= list.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
    DBObject obj = iterator.next();

    String id = (String) obj.get("_id");
    int times = Integer.parseInt(obj.get("times").toString());

    System.out.println("ID IS "+id+" time: "+times);
}
```

But technically, the for loop mentioned by @Aqua is a lot cleaner to use.  This answer was just to clarify the why, not the how.

Answer (score 1):

One possible flaw in your code is you are calling Iterator.next() method multiple times. Store its value in a variable and use variable instead of calling multiple times.

Eg:

```
DBObject obj = list.iterator().next();
String id = (String) obj.get("_id"); 

int times = Integer.parseInt(obj.get("times").toString());`
```